# Is there a second Church-Kleene ordinal?

Tags: supremum-and-infimum, ordinals, transfinite-recursion

Given the Church-Kleene ordinal $\omega^{CK}_1$, the supremum of all recursive ordinals, can we go further and derive $\omega^{CK}_2$, $\omega^{CK}_3$, $\omega^{CK}_\omega$ or $\omega^{CK}_{\omega^{CK}_1}$?

Even beyond that, $\mathcal{O}^+$ is the supremum of all writable ordinals and $\mathcal{O}^{++}$ is the supremum of all eventually writable ordinals, is this also extendable? i.e. can we have $\mathcal{O}^{+++}$ or $\mathcal{O}^{++++++}$?

If they do exist, I'm assuming the supremums of these sequences are less than the first uncountable ordinal $\omega_1$?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A good rule of thumb in computability theory is, *everything can be relativized.* (Before going further, I'll link to [this lovely summary of many countable ordinals of computability-theoretic significance](http://www.madore.org/~david/math/ordinal-zoo.pdf), by David Madore; it's not immediately relevant to your question, but in answering your question we'll be inexorably drawn to its themes.)

Let's talk about $\omega_1^{CK}$, since I don't really know anything about writeable ordinals. $\omega_1^{CK}$ has two natural definitions:

- The first ordinal $\alpha$ with no computable copy.
- The first ordinal $\alpha>\omega$ such that $L_\alpha\models $KP.

Here "KP" is [Kripke-Platek set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kripke%E2%80%93Platek_set_theory), a weak fragment of ZFC. "$L_\alpha$" denotes the $\alpha$th level of the [constructible universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructible_universe#What_is_L.3F), and an ordinal $\alpha$ is *admissible* if $L_\alpha\models$KP.

Both of these definitions generalize:

- Given $r\subseteq\omega$, we let $\omega_1^{CK}(r)$ denote the first ordinal with no $r$-computable copy. *(This is usually denoted by "$\omega_1^r$," but I dislike that a bit.)*
- Given an ordinal $\alpha$, we write "$\omega_1^{Ad}(\alpha)$" for the least admissible $>\alpha$. *(This is usually denoted by "$\alpha^+$," but that's even worse.)* Note that this suggests that we could write "$\omega_1^{Ad}=\omega_1^{CK}$;" I certainly wouldn't object.

It's easy to show that $\omega_1^{CK}(r)$ and $\omega_1^{Ad}(\alpha)$ each exist, regardless of $r$ and $\alpha$. It turns out that they each generalize $\omega_1^{CK}$ *in the same way*!

The simplest generalization of $\omega_\alpha^{CK}$ is via admissibility:

> $\omega_\alpha^{Ad}$ is the $\alpha$th admissible ordinal greater than $\omega$.

Another generalization, a bit more complicated, comes from computability directly:

> For $\alpha$ an ordinal, we write $\omega_1^{CK}(\alpha)$ for the least ordinal $\beta$ for which there is some copy of $\alpha$ (= binary relation on $\omega$ with ordertype $\alpha$) which does not compute a copy of $\beta$.

*Note that this definition only makes sense for $\alpha$ **countable**; this can be fixed by looking at forcing extensions in which $\alpha$ is countable. The general theme of computability in generic extensions is a very interesting one to me, and is something I work on.*

It turns out that these two ideas are the same! This is due to Sacks, following Kripke and Platek:

> $\alpha$ is admissible iff there is some $r\subseteq\omega$ such that $\alpha=\omega_1^{CK}(r)$. In particular, this means that we have $\omega_1^{CK}(\alpha)=\omega_1^{Ad}(\alpha)$ for all (countable) ordinals $\alpha$.

*Incidentally, this explains why you've never seen the notation "$\omega_1^{Ad}$" before - there's really no point in having it. But I think it's useful to introduce it early on, in order to keep the distinction clear and make Sacks' result more immediately impressive.*

So this shows that not only can we continue to define versions of $\omega_1^{CK}$, but it relativizes *robustly*. And these relativizations are extremely useful: admissible sets provide contexts for generalized recursion theory (["$\alpha$-recursion theory"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_recursion_theory)), and Sacks' characterization via computability is a powerful tool in their study.

---

Now what about $\mathcal{O}$?

*There's a notational issue here: "$\mathcal{O}$" is more commonly used to describe [a specific set of natural numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene%27s_O) .*

Well, there's a natural generalization of it, following the second generalization of $\omega_1^{CK}$:

> Let $\mathcal{O}_2$ be the least ordinal $\alpha$ for which there is some copy of $\mathcal{O}$ relatively to which $\alpha$ is not writeable.

More generally, for $r\subseteq\omega$ write "$\mathcal{O}(r)$" for the least ordinal not writeable relative to $r$. A good understanding of the ordinal should provide an equivalent characterization of those ordinals of the form $\mathcal{O}(r)$ in terms of the axioms the relevant levels of $L$ should satisfy (and Madore's article mentions several results in this theme).

Similarly, we can generalize $\mathcal{O}^+$ by replacing "writeable" with "eventually writeable."

However, you asked something different: about the transition $\mathcal{O}\rightarrow\mathcal{O}^+$. I'm not sure what should come next, since I don't know what operation corresponds to adding the word "eventually." There is a precedent, though: the relationship between writeability and eventual writeability seems very weakly similar to that between computability and  [limit computability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computation_in_the_limit), which of course is connected to [an operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_jump). So I'm optimistic here. But maybe an actual expert can chime in here ...

Comment: I love this site. Thank you so much! I'm going to check out the article you linked and I might come back with a tiny question, but this seems like a lot of what I asked in the question!

Comment: @user3684314 Glad I could help! The bibliography in the Madore article is especially useful; you should check out the sources it mentions (especially Sacks' "Higher Recursion Theory," Barwise' "Admissible sets and structures," and the volumes "Generalized Recursion Theory I and II," in my opinion).

Comment: Brilliant! I actually have one question so far based on the "Zoo" article, namely (1.22), which describes the countable collapse of $\epsilon_{I+1}$ where $I$ is the first inaccessible cardinal. Wouldn't that be much larger than the Church-Kleene ordinal?

Comment: @user3684314 Nope - it's actually much *smaller*. The collapsing process is one used in proof theory, and produces countable ordinals (even if it starts with ridiculously huge cardinals) - see [this wiki summary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_collapsing_function).

Comment: Absolutely incredible. This kind of stuff never ceases to amaze me. Thanks!

Comment: last thing I promise-- so I've seen the notation $\psi(\psi_I(0))$, the countable collapse of $\psi_I(0)$, the omega fixed point. Is this ordinal larger or smaller than $\psi(\epsilon_{I+1})$ (1.22.) in Madore's "Zoo"?

Comment: @user3684314 If you don't mind, could you provide the definition of the $\psi$ function from Madore? Anyways, if both $\psi$'s are equivalent, then$$\psi(\psi_I(0))=\psi(\Omega_{\Omega_{\ddots}})\ll\psi(\varepsilon_{I+1})$$where $\ll$ is used to signify a large gap in magnitude.

Comment: Err... I'm not sure, it seems like it's the "countable collapse" of whatever is in the parenthesis (in Madore). In regards to the collapse of the first inaccessible is [here](http://googology.wikia.com/wiki/%CE%A8(%CF%88%E1%B5%A2(0))), says that it's "Michael Rathjen's ordinal collapsing function". (Sorry if that's not enough info, please let me know if you need more!)

Comment: No problem @user3684314 , generally $\psi_I(x)$ can be thought of as fixed-points of $f:x\mapsto\Omega_x$, and$$\psi(\varepsilon_{I+1})=\psi(I^{I^{I^{\dots}}})=\psi(\psi_I(I^{I^{I^{\dots}}}))\gg\psi(\psi_I(I))=\psi(\psi_I(\psi_I(\psi_I(\dots))))=\dots\gg\psi(\psi_I(0))$$To give you an idea of how it works.

Comment: @user3684314 If you'd like to talk more on how the extended $\psi$ function works, you can ping me [in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65947/mathworks).

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt thank you so much! This stuff is way above my pay grade, but it's super interesting and I really appreciate all of your help!