# Is it possible to construct a model of oracle Turing machines that correspond to $\omega_n^\text{CK}$, where $n$ is greater than $1$?

Tags: logic, ordinals, turing-machines, oracles

I have found the following quotes. Quote $1$ ( [source](http://googology.wikia.com/wiki/User_blog_comment:Fejfo/Super_Fast_Beaver_Hierarchies_and_a_weird_OCF/@comment-1605058-20180806150910/@comment-30754445-20180806185516?permalink=53119#comm-53119) ):

> In computability theory, Turing Machines+BB oracles correspond to the same ordinal as ordinary Turing Machines ($\omega_1^\text{CK}$). In googology, BB oracles correspond to $ \omega_1^\text{CK} \times 2 $ to the FGH.

(note that “BB oracles” here denote the oracles that can compute the Busy Beaver function for the lower-order Turing machines).

Quote $2$ ( [source](http://googology.wikia.com/wiki/User_blog_comment:Bubby3/Church_Kleene_ordinal_question/@comment-1605058-20170810162247?permalink=38399#comm-38399) ):

> With access to the halting oracle, you still cannot compute ordinals greater than $ \omega_1^\text{CK} $. The set of computable ordinals is, in fact, still the same. However, given an oracle for $ \omega_1^\text{CK} $, we can compute larger ordinals, and in fact the ordinals computable from $ \omega_1^\text{CK} $ are exactly the ones below $ \omega_2^\text{CK} $.

(in this quote, I don’t understand what “an oracle for $\omega_1^\text{CK}$” means).

Quote $3$ ( [source](http://googology.wikia.com/wiki/Talk:Xi_function) ):

> Adam Goucher admited he was wrong when he first wrote about strength of $\Sigma_2(n)$. It is actually $\omega_2^{CK}$, well over $\omega_1^{CK} \times 2$.

(note that $\Sigma_2(n)$ here denotes the Busy Beaver function for the second-order oracle Turing machines, that is, Turing machines equipped with an oracle that can compute the Busy Beaver function for the first-order Turing machines).

It seems like Quote $3$ contradicts Quote $1$, and the question is: is it possible (if yes, then how?) to construct a model of Turing machines that correspond to $ \omega_n^\text{CK} $ in computability theory, assuming that $n$ can be extended to any natural number greater than $1$? What function would the oracles of such machines compute?

**EDIT**

Quote $4$ ( [source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Admissible_ordinal) ):

> The first two admissible ordinals are ω and $\omega _{1}^{\mathrm {CK} }$ (the least non-recursive ordinal, also called the Church–Kleene ordinal). Any regular uncountable cardinal is an admissible ordinal.
>
> By a theorem of Sacks, the countable admissible ordinals are exactly those constructed in a manner similar to the Church-Kleene ordinal, but for Turing machines with oracles.

Can anyone explain how exactly such construction is done? I cannot find any accessible explanation online.

There are relatively similar questions, but they do not address the described problem:

- [Is there a second Church-Kleene ordinal?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2363328/is-there-a-second-church-kleene-ordinal)
- [What classification of countable ordinals above $\omega _{1}^{\mathrm {CK} }$ exists?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/465400/what-classification-of-countable-ordinals-above-omega-1ck-exists)

Comment: Just so you know, all the "strength of function in terms of ordinals" claims are almost completely unsubstantiated - there is no formal way in which they are true. For the record, I am in large part a cause for the claim in quote 3, but since then I have learnt better and can assure you $\Sigma_2$ in no sensible way reaches $\omega_2^{CK}$.

Comment: Regarding quote 2, "oracle for $\omega_1^{CK}$" is any oracle which encodes a well-order of order type $\omega_1^{CK}$. Results due to Sacks imply that with such an oracle we can compute all ordinals below $\omega_2^{CK}$, and for suitable choice of this oracle we will no larger ordinals will be computable with this oracle.

Comment: Again, we run into the problem of what "[a function] reaches [an ordinal]" is supposed to mean, but for the former, there is a reasonable answer of "doesn't reach $\omega_2^{CK}$", because $\omega$-th order halting oracle doesn't let us compute ordinals greater than $\omega_1^{CK}$. For $BB_{\omega_1^{CK}}$ we reach another issue of how exactly we would define $\omega_1^{CK}$-th order oracle - there is no canonical way to do that (for recursive ordinals, we can show all (computable) choices give essentially the same oracle, but that fails for nonrecursive ordinals)

Comment: @Wojowu: —> we run into the problem of what "[a function] reaches [an ordinal]" is supposed to mean <— In this context, I think that this is the Busy Beaver function for Turing machines with an oracle which encodes a well-order of order type $\omega_n^\text{CK}$. But I still don't understand how to define these oracles. Even if there is no **canonical** way to do this, I think that any **mathematically reasonable** way would be enough.

Comment: @Wojowu Can you give a specific reference (or references) for the result you mentioned in the second comment below the question? Also am I right in assuming that $\omega_2^{CK}=\omega_1^{CK}(\omega_1^{CK})$ is  considered as definition of $\omega_2^{CK}$? Here I am assuming the following def. for $\omega_1^{CK}(\alpha)$ from an answer in linked thread (in question): "For $\alpha$ an ordinal, we write $\omega_1^{CK}(\alpha)$ for the least ordinal $\beta$ for which there is some copy of $\alpha$ (= binary relation on $\omega$ with ordertype $\alpha$) which does not compute a copy of $\beta$."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Throughout, by "structure" I mean "countable structure in a computable language." I'm also assuming you're comfortable both with [Turing reducibility $\le_T$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_reduction) - which lets us avoid unnecessary verbiage about machines and oracles - and with the idea of reals coding copies of structures (see SSequence's answer, specifically the $\omega\cdot2$ example).*

---

- We begin with the *computability* side. For $r$ a real, we let $\omega_1^{CK}(r)$ be the smallest ordinal with no $r$-computable copy; equivalently, the supremum of the ordinals which *do* have $r$-computable copies. For a structure $\mathcal{A}$ we let $\omega_1^{CK}(\mathcal{A})$ be the smallest ordinal not computed by some$^1$ copy of $\mathcal{A}$; precisely, $$\omega_1^{CK}(\mathcal{A})=\min\{\omega_1^{CK}(r):r\mbox{ codes a copy of $\mathcal{A}$}\}.$$

  - "$\omega_1^{CK}(r)$" is not how that appears in the literature - rather, you'll see "$\omega_1^r$" - but I strongly prefer it, since it avoids clashing with set-theoretic notation. Note also that we can conflate a real $r\subseteq\omega$ with the structure $\hat{r}$ consisting of the natural numbers with successor and a unary predicate for $r$, and it's easy to check that $\omega_1^{CK}(r)=\omega_1^{CK}(\hat{r})$, so everything lines up nicely.
- Next, we look at the *admissibility* side. For $\alpha$ an arbitrary ordinal, we let $\omega_\alpha^{ad}$ denote the $\alpha$th admissible ordinal: that is, the $\alpha$th ordinal whose corresponding level of $L$ satisfies KP. *Note that this definition has nothing to do with computability theory on the face of it* (and in fact, doesn't even require $\alpha$ to be countable!). We'll also write "$\omega_1^{ad}(\beta)$" for the first admissible ordinal $>\beta$; in particular, $\omega_1^{ad}(\omega_\alpha^{ad})=\omega_{\alpha+1}^{ad}$.

  - **Nobody uses** this notation, since by Sacks' result it's completely redundant. However, distinguishing at this stage in the game between admissibility concerns and computability concerns is I think very helpful, so I hope you'll forgive me the introduction of soon-to-be-stupid notation.
- Now [Sacks' result](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3095770/28111) (plus a bit of thought) shows that $$\omega_1^{CK}(\alpha)=\omega_1^{ad}(\alpha)\mbox{ for every countable ordinal $\alpha$}.$$ This is why you never see the "$ad$" notation: it's made completely irrelevant! **In particular, "$\omega_\alpha^{CK}$" is just our "$\omega_\alpha^{ad}$."**

  - Moreover, Sacks' result immediately implies that $\omega_1^{CK}(\mathcal{A})$, being the minimum of a set of admissible ordinals,is itself admissible.
  - Also, via forcing we can make sense of this for even uncountable $\alpha$. But that's really a side issue.

---

$^1$Note the careful quantification over copies here (and the implicit focus on "optimally simple" copies) in our definition of $\omega_1^{CK}(\mathcal{A})$. This is fundamental: **different copies of the same structure can behave very differently**, and we need to address this if our definitions are to be interesting at all.

Specifically, we can have very simple *structures* coded by very complicated *reals*: e.g. "swapping" $2n$ and $2n+1$ whenever $n\in 0'$ gives a copy of $\omega$ which computes $0'$, and more generally we can get copies of $\omega$ of arbitrarily high complexity. In fact, [this (almost) always happens](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/journal-of-symbolic-logic/article/degrees-coded-in-jumps-of-orderings/346FEEB16ABD097735D240ED3ED67056). So in order to say anything interesting, we need to talk about what *all* copies of a given structure can do.

- Note: this is what Wojowu's comment "Results due to Sacks imply that with such an oracle we can compute all ordinals below $\omega_2^{CK}$, and **for suitable choice of** this oracle *[typo removed]* no larger ordinals will be computable with this oracle." Obviously *some* copies of $\omega_2^{CK}$, when used as oracles, will let us compute a ton of extra junk; the point is that nothing beyond $\omega_2^{CK}$ is *necessarily* computable from a copy of $\omega_1^{CK}$.

What we're ultimately getting at here is the idea of **reducibilities between structures**. Here we're looking just at Muchnik (weak) reducibility: $\mathcal{A}\le_w\mathcal{B}$ if every real coding a copy of $\mathcal{B}$ computes some real coding a copy of $\mathcal{A}$. There are other reducibilities too - most immediately, Medvedev (strong) reducibility - but for these sorts of questions we're really in the Muchnik realm, at least for now.

EDIT: An important point here which I think will substantially clarify things is that *Muchnik reducibility extends $\le$* - if $\mathcal{A}\ge_w\alpha$ and $\beta<\alpha$ then $\mathcal{A}\ge_w\beta$. In particular this means that $\omega_1^{CK}(\mathcal{A})$ is both the *least* ordinal *without* a copy computable from every copy of $\mathcal{A}$, and the *supremum* of the ordinals which *do* have copies computable from every copy of $\mathcal{A}$.

EDIT THE SECOND: And here's a way of constructing such a "sufficiently simple" copy of $\omega_1^{CK}$: a copy of $\omega_1^{CK}$ can be computed straightforwardly from [Kleene's $\mathcal{O}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kleene%27s_O), but$^2$ $\mathcal{O}$ is in $L_{\omega_2^{CK}}$ and so every ordinal with a copy computable from $\mathcal{O}$ is $<\omega_2^{CK}$. All of this requires a bit of familiarity with admissible sets and $L_{\omega_1^{CK}}$ in particular; Sacks' book is as usual a good source on the topic.

Comment: > the point is that nothing beyond $\omega_2^{CK}$ is _necessarily_ computable from a copy of $\omega_1^{CK}$ < I am not sure I understand the word "beyond" here correctly. Does it mean "below" or "above"?

Comment: @lyricallywicked **above**. If $r$ is a real coding a copy of $\omega_1^{CK}$, then every ordinal less than $\omega_1^{CK}$ has a copy computable from $r$ (and no ordinal $\ge\omega_2^{CK}$ is guaranteed to have a copy computable from $r$).

Comment: You mentioned "every ordinal less than $\omega_1^{CK}$" and "ordinal $\ge \omega_2^{CK}$". But where are _all_ ordinals less than $\omega_2^{CK}$? Are their copies guaranteed to be computable?

Comment: @lyricallywicked Whoops, sorry - the second "$\omega_1^{CK}$" in my previous comment should be an "$\omega_2^{CK}$." See my recent edit, which I think should help.

Comment: It only remains for me to clarify one thing. In your statement "If $r$ is a real coding a copy of $\omega_1^{CK}$, then every ordinal less than $\omega_2^{CK}$ has a copy computable from $r$" (from the comment above), can the "a real coding a copy" part be replaced with "a real coding _any_ copy"? If yes, I am not sure why you emphasized the "for suitable choice of" part in the answer: _any_ real (if it codes _any_ copy of $\omega_1^{CK}$) is suitable!

Comment: @lyricallywicked Sorry, this is a bit of messy language on my part. "every ordinal less than $\omega_2^{CK}$ has a copy computable from $r$" should be "every ordinal less than $\omega_2^{CK}$ has a real $s$ computable from $r$, which computes a copy of it" - basically, "a real coding a copy of" *is* a copy of. This is something that happens when I both try to avoid saying to little but also don't put enough care into saying things correctly. Probably the best thing to do would be to use "copy of $\mathcal{A}$" to refer to *any real which* codes a structure isomorphic to $\mathcal{A}$. (cont'd)

Comment: (This then makes phrases like "real coding a copy of" redundant.) In this language, what I said above would be just: "If $r$ is a copy of $\omega_1^{CK}$, then every ordinal $<\omega_2^{CK}$ has an $r$-computable copy; on the other hand, there is a copy $s$ of $\omega_1^{CK}$ which doesn't compute copies of any ordinal $\ge\omega_2^{CK}$."

Comment: @lyricallywicked I've added a bit about producing a "sufficiently simple" copy of $\omega_1^{CK}$.

Answer (score 0):

This really should be a comment, but probably too long for it. Regarding [Quote2], I think it follows from a general and rather well-known result. Let $A \subseteq \mathbb{N}$ be any set such that $A\in HA$ (HA=hyperarithmethic). Then you can't generate $\omega_{CK}$ with a program that has access to the set $A$. If you denote $H$ as halt-set then because $H \in HYP$, one gets the result mentioned in the first half of [Quote2].

I do not have any familiarity with the result personally though (it was mentioned in the first question I asked an year ago).

Also regarding the second half of [Quote2], since you mentioned you don't understand what an "oracle for $\omega_{CK}$ means", here are few comments that might help. I am not good with formal stuff so I hope there isn't an issue in the wording. But formally I think it means having an access to function(or an equivalent set basically) which represents the well-order relation ...... corresponding to the well-ordering of $\omega_{CK}$ in terms of $\mathbb{N}$.

For example, if you defined a function $LE:\mathbb{N}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ so that:

$LE(x,y)=1$ if and only if $x \le y$

then $LE$ represent the well-order relation ..... corresponding to well-ordering of $\mathbb{N}$ with order-type $\omega$.

Another example is:

$LE(x,y)=1$ if $x=y$

If $x \ne y$ then:

$LE(x,y)=$ truth value of $x<y$ ---- if $x$ is even and $y$ is even

$LE(x,y)=1$ ---- if $x$ is even and $y$ is odd

$LE(x,y)=0$ ---- if $x$ is odd and $y$ is even

$LE(x,y)=$ truth value of $x<y$ ---- if $x$ is odd and $y$ is odd

If you look at it carefully enough, $LE$ here represents the well-order relation corresponding to well-ordering of $\mathbb{N}$ with order-type $\omega \cdot 2$.

Similarly you can also describe a well-ordering of $\mathbb{N}$ with order-type $\omega^2$ using a pairing function (a function describing a 1-1 correspondence between $\mathbb{N}^2$ and $\mathbb{N}$).

---

Now coming back to the comment in second half of [Quote2]. If you denote $\alpha=\omega_{CK}=\omega^{CK}_1$ and denote, for example, $\beta$ as the smallest ordinal that can't be generated using a program that has access to the well-order relation describing the well-ordering of $\omega_{CK}$ in terms of $\mathbb{N}$. Then I hope you can easily see why the following should all be true (via a positive demonstration of a program that does it):

$\beta > \alpha \cdot 2$

$\beta > \alpha ^ 2$

$\beta > \alpha ^ \alpha$

$\beta > \gamma=sup\{\alpha, \alpha^\alpha, \alpha^{\alpha^\alpha},..... \}$

this goes on...

Comment: But there is one more subtlety to it in the sense that the choice of well-order relation for $\omega_{CK}$ could change $\beta$. See the second comment by @Wojowu below the question. I am guessing that possibly the phrase "and for suitable choice of this oracle" is meant to reflect this.

Comment: Bumped to correct somewhat misleading phrase "well-ordering of $\omega^2$ (in terms of $\mathbb{N}$)"